# Bayesian, causal: latent variable estimation

Tags: bayesian, causality, latent-variable

I have 3 variables: X, Y, U. U is unobserved. I know that X -> Y and U -> Y and U -> X. So U is a confounder.

For example: U = IQ, X = education and Y = income.

I want to estimate the latent variable U so that I estimate the effect of X on Y more accurately.

Let's say I can estimate these equations where e1 and e2 are the errors, and U is estimated as well.

(1) Y ~ X + U + e1

(2) X ~ U + e2

U is like a shared idiosyncratic factor.

Can I force U and (e1, e2) to be independent of each other via a prior covariance matrix?